What's to prevent us from concluding that Revelation 13:3 has been fulfilled through Trump?
The Book of Revelation 13:3 speaks of a beast that received a deadly wound on the head and the wound was healed and the world followed that beast in wonder.
Revelation 13:3

One of the beast's heads looked like it had sustained a mortal wound, but its fatal wound was healed. Rapt with amazement, the whole world followed the beast.

The wound on Trump was on his head and the whole world has followed his story with amazement, and his wound is healing(bandaged), is this prophecy in fulfillment or has been fulfilled?
Do we have an id on the beast in Revelation?
The whole world is amazed because his thinking to turn his head and look at the bill board saved his life.
Also because the Book of Revelation is a mathematical eventuality, the mark of the beast is a human number, the beast continues for forty two months and other important details.
The whole world followed Trump and he just won.

Given that prophecy is proved by it coming true, I'd say by waiting to see whether your suggestion is or is not the fulfillment.  I'm sure I'm risking being a little rude; however, allow me to share a personal story.  Shortly after I became a Christian I started listening to a Christian broadcast solely focused on prophetic interpretation.  After about 6 months I noticed two things:  1. It was more about hyping current headlines to fit a Bible verse (or the other way around) than it was coherent exposition of texts; 2. None of it was coming true.

I have voted to close this question as it is a matter of opinion.

Up-voting this one (along with all the answers) because of the number of people I know that tend to interpret events like this, and really need to read these kinds of answers...

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Really?  Here are the reasons that Rev 13:1-10 is definitely not D J Trump:

Trump was not mortally wounded - it was a very minor flesh wound.
Trump does not have seven heads and 10 horns
Trump did not receive his power from the dragon who is "that ancient serpent called the devil and Satan, the deceiver of the whole world" (Rev 12:9)  Trump was elected via the people of the USA.
Trump was never crowned with 10 crowns
Trump was elected for four years not just 42 months (V5)
Trump does not and never did have "authority over every tribe and people and tongue and nation" (V7)
Trump did not originate in the sea - he was born in New York

Further, such an interpretation of D J Trump as the beast of Rev 13:1-10 would imply the following as well:

Trump being worshipped as a god (V4)
Trump speaking arrogant blasphemies (V5)
Trump persecuting the saints (= Christians; indeed, many Christians have vocally supported Trump)
etc

Therefore, whatever/whoever the sea beast of Rev 13 is, it definitely NOT Donald John Trump.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Among many reasons, there is the fact that the wound sustained by his head was not mortal. I understand that John Kennedy, who really was killed by a shot in the head, is already favoured by conspiracy theorists.
In any case, we need not assume that this verse applies to an individual. One theory (the one advocated in my own book) premises that the beast from the sea represents the power of the state, and each "head" of the beast is a domineeering political state. I can think of at least three different states which "died" and came back to life in the twentieth century alone- Imperial Germany, Imperial Russia, and Imperial China. In the right circumstances, the world might "wonder after" the next one that revives.
Instead of jumping to conclusions on the basis of a single verse. why not wait for the rest of the chapter to be fulfilled, including the violent persecution of the church.

I can argue the wound was deadly because he survived by an inch and he also bled

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, you can indeed argue that, and I'm sure others will. I would just ask you to consider also that this approach of applying Revelation verses has been going on for hundreds of years, and time after time a particular person or organisation is tagged to something in the book. And every time it's a different person. Which convinces me personally that this whole approach is wrong, and we should not be reading Revelation that way....

@SoFewAgainstSoMany,  If someone said to me a month ago that your verse would be fulfilled by Trump's shooting, I'd be impressed and maybe start to take it seriously. But I think it's wrong because the connections are always made after the event. So we're not interpreting what the book actually says, we're reading stuff into it.

@PeterKirkpatrick "the connections are always made after the event. So we're not interpreting what the book actually says, we're reading stuff into it" quite a lot of prophetic fulfillment claims are like this, actually

@AviAvraham, true. Which is why I'm suspicious of them all. And it's one reason why I believe that Jesus is the Messiah: He himself applied Old Testament prophecy to his own life, death and resurrection prior to the event. Especially true regarding the resurrection.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany That means he almost received a deadly wound.  The wound he actually did receive was not deadly or even significant.

The fact that we are living in the "mystery" age of God's grace (Rom 16:25, Eph chapter 3, Col 1:26-27) and not that of covenant "prophecy" for Israel (Jer 31:31, Heb 8:8) should be reason enough to not come to that conclusion.  Believers await and look for the coming of Christ, not the antichrist.
Regardless, a shot through the ear lobe would not be indicative of a potentially fatal "deadly wound".  Also, the gauze pad on Trump's ear would certainly not be marvelous of how an actual "deadly wound was healed".
Revelation 13:3

And I saw one of his heads as it were wounded to death; and his deadly wound was healed: and all the world wondered after the beast.

I have seen zero evidence that "all the world wondered" after Donald Trump.  Some have, but certainly not "all the world".  Again, if it were to be true, then no one reading this was ever a member of the church, the body of Christ, as that group will not be present on earth when the identity of "that wicked" is actually revealed.

the turning of the head has fascinated the world

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Ecc 9:11 "I returned, and saw under the sun, that the race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, neither yet bread to the wise, nor yet riches to men of understanding, nor yet favour to men of skill; but time and chance happeneth to them all."

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  "Fascinated the world"? You cannot be serious! All the media hype is a flash in the pan that will quickly move to other matters, such as today's Microsoft IT outage that has crippled global systems. It's mainly religiously fanatical so-called 'evangelicals' who are adoring this man despite him being a convicted criminal. 'The whole world' my foot!

@Anne, Trump could be one of the heads, the heads are simply world rulers and the only world ruler who has a mortal wound that is healing is Trump. Trump is one of those heads, I have a friend who has a ten year research on this and at first I was also skeptical but Trump moving the capital of Israel to Jerusalem and this prove something divine is around the corner

Unbelievably, this has happened before. France24 recounts: August 22, 1962: French President Charles de Gaulle and his wife are being whisked by car through the Paris suburb of Petit-Clamart for a flight back to their country home, when a man on the side of the road waves a newspaper... A group of right-wing extremists spring into action and rake the presidential Citroen DS with gunfire. Three of the bullets penetrate the bodywork and pass within inches of De Gaulle's head but he and his wife Yvonne miraculously escape unharmed. "They're such bad shots!,"

France's World War II hero later jokes about the attempt on his life which shocks the country and gives De Gaulle an opportunity to boost the powers of his office.  De Gaulle immediately turned the situation to his advantage by appearing defiant and appealing to the people, as did Trump.

The beast of Rev. 13:3 is not of our time, nor any future time.  That beast was living when the book of Rev. was written, before the temple in Jerusalem was destroyed.

And I stood upon the sand of the sea, and I saw out of the sea a beast coming up, having seven heads and ten horns, and upon its horns ten diadems, and upon its heads a name of evil speaking,


2 and the beast that I saw was like to a leopard, and its feet as of a bear, and its mouth as the mouth of a lion, and the dragon did give to it his power, and his throne, and great authority.


3 And I saw one of its heads as slain to death, and its deadly stroke was healed, and all the earth did wonder after the beast, ....


18 Here is the wisdom! He who is having the understanding, let him count the number of the beast, for the number of a man it is, and its number [is] 666.  (Rev. 13:1-3, 18 YLT)

That beast was a man whose name numbered six hundred and sixty six.  This was a known method of gematria used by the Jews.  Rev. 13:3 was a beast that came out of the sea which was the symbol YHVH used for the pagan nations that surrounded the land or earth of Israel / Judea.  The present tense "is" indicates a man existing at the time the book was written, approx. AD 66-68.  This verse ties directly to Rev. 17.

3 and he carried me away to a wilderness in the Spirit, and I saw a woman sitting upon a scarlet-coloured beast, full of names of evil-speaking, having seven heads and ten horns,...


9 `Here [is] the mind that is having wisdom; the seven heads are seven mountains, upon which the woman doth sit,


10 and there are seven kings, the five did fall, and the one is, the other did not yet come, and when he may come, it behoveth him to remain a little time; (Rev. 17:3, 9-10, YLT)

The king of that sea beast that "is" in Rev. 17:10 existed and was ruling in the first century AD.  That sea beast with the 7 heads and 10 horns was the old Roman empire.  The one that "is," the 6th king of that sea beast nation was living and present when John wrote that prophesy.  It was Nero.  The gematria for Nero's name is 666.
Excerpt from my post The Beast of Revelation (here
"The number 666 was used to conceal the name of the man that was in power and ruling at the time John wrote Revelation (A.D. 66 -68), so as to protect the readers of the book who were suffering his extreme persecution.  John could not be forthright and name Nero for fear of further drawing his anger.   The numbering method used to signify the name was a common practice of the day for numbering letters of a name.  It was used in both the Greek and Hebrew languages.
But, the Jewish Christian, and indeed all Jews, thought and wrote the name of Nero in Hebrew.  Their language was Hebrew, so the symbol was to the Hebrew spelling, “Neron Kesar.”   Only the consonants carried the numeric value.   Vowels were not included or numbered.
Rendered in the English (as I don’t have a Hebrew keyboard), NRWN QSR:
N = 50; R = 200; W = 6; N = 50; Q = 100; S= 60; R = 200…. for a total of 666.
In the Aramaic, RSQ NWRN:
R = 200; S = 60; Q = 100; N = 50; W = 6; R = 200; N = 50…. for a total of 666.
Nero Caesar was THE antichrist of Revelation.  There were and are many antichrists, as anyone who denies Christ is an antichrist.  But, the one numbered by John, whom he was warning the persecuted Christians about in the first century A.D. was Nero."
Revelation was John's Olivet discourse that prophesied the destruction of Jerusalem.  The woman symbolized Jerusalem, the seat of the temple of the Holy Place of old covenant Israel to whom YHVH had been a husband.  Before the revolt against Rome, the Sanhedrin has been in league with the Caesars of Rome as Judea had become a province of Rome under Pompey in about 60-61 BC.
Revelation is not a prophesy for our future, and it is not a prophesy of an end-of-the-world destruction.  The sign of the rainbow in the throne scene in Rev. 4:3 was the same sign God gave to Noah (Gen. 9:13) that never again would He curse the ground for man's sake (Gen. 8:21).
The sign of the rainbow around the throne was the signal to John that the judgment promised was not about the entire earth, but only upon those of that prophesy - the limited earth of the nation of Judea and the surrounding areas of that Roman empire.
Therefor, Rev. 13:3 is not about any tyrant "beast" ruler of our day, and it is not about Pres. Trump.
See these posts that show more of the evidences from the scriptures:
The Signs of Rev. - Part I: The Time of His Coming
The Signs of Rev. - Part IV: The Throne Scene
The Signs of Rev. - Part V: The Animal Symbols...
The Signs of Rev. - Part VI: Judgment Day
The Fig Tree & the Mountain
Frequent Mistakes - Part I: The Wounded Head
Testing the Spirits - Part II: The End
Testing the Spirits - Part III: Daniel's Lot

"Revelation is not a prophesy for our future, and it is not a prophesy of an end-of-the-world destruction." Could you elaborate on this? Revelation 20 - 22 definitely seems to be prophecy of the end-of-the-world, including its destruction and final judgment.

That is the current take on Rev. 20-22, but that does not hold true when u examine the scriptures..  Rev. 1:1 "things which must shortly come to pass"  Rev. 22:6 "things which must shortly be done"  Book marks front & back & includes Rev. 20-22.  It was about the end of the Mosaic covenant & the end of that sacrificial temple in Jerusalem which was profane once Christ became the last blood sacrifice God would ever again accept for forgiveness of sins.  Judgment occurred after the temple was destroyed in AD 70, & the realm of the dead - Hades - was thrown out.  Pls read the posts I've listed.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

“What's to prevent us from concluding that Revelation 13:3 has been fulfilled through Trump?”
Against my better judgement, but considering 8,000+ views already . . . several answers immediately come to mind, including

Not making wild speculations in the first place
Rightly dividing the
word of truth, and
Not being carried about by every wind of
doctrine.

Do you remember the previous speculations about Mikhail Gorbachev?


“Then, if you take the gematria values of the Cyrillic alphabet
multiply them by his birthdate in the old calendar and divide the
result by URS (the Russian abbreviation of the Soviet Union), you’ll
get 666 in base 7! Plus, he died on August 30, 2022, so he will rise
from the dead 3-1/2 years from then, in February 2026! This is all
detailed in a new book, “The Beast Returns” for the low, low price of
$19.95.”

Oh, please stop! (cry)

Even after Trump moved the capital to Jerusalem? Even after he received a fatal wound as one of the heads?

No, Donald Trump moved the U.S. embassy to Jerusalem, recognizing Israel's historical capital. Trump had his right ear pierced in an unusual way, but this is normally not considered a "fatal wound." In biblical prophecy, animals represent empires, heads represent governments, wings might represent significant allies, and horns represent significant leaders. Revelation is packed with allusions and symbols from the Tanakh. A fatally wounded head restored to life in the context of the book of Daniel would represent a destroyed nation that's miraculously brought back to life.

The presidency is an organization, nevertheless an evangelical prophesied about the attempt on his life some few months ago and now I believe that evangelist to be inspired by God. The deep state has killed too many American leaders out of the love for money because money is the root of all evil. Kennedy tried to fight the deep state and look at what happened to him, it almost happened to Trump. May God protect American leaders.
